# Struggling to structure libgdx project

Tags: java, libgdx

I know this question might get taken down but I'm going to ask it anyway.

I've been trying to make a draughts game in Java using Libgdx; I've been using Stage2D as well.

I don't know how to structure the project as I plan on having separate classes for the board, game, players, pieces and GUI. Also, I have written some code to draw a board, however, it doesn't seem to work with Stage2D.

I still want to figure this out myself, as I want to learn from this project. So, please do not give too much away.

However, I don't know how to draw the board or start this project.

All the resources and tutorials I have found online have been very unclear. I don't really know what to do.

```java
package com.mygdx.game;

public enum Color {
    BLACK, WHITE
}
```

```java
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;

public class GUI {
    float r_brown = (float) 163 / 255;
    float g_brown = (float) 102 / 255;
    float b_brown = (float) 46 / 255;

    float r_cream = (float) 240 / 255;
    float g_cream = (float) 187 / 255;
    float b_cream = (float) 108 / 255;

    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    public GUI(ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer, OrthographicCamera camera) {
        this.shapeRenderer = shapeRenderer;
        this.camera = camera;
    }

    public void drawGUI() {
    }
}
```

```java
package com.mygdx.game;

public enum Type {
    SOLDIER, KING
}
```

```java
package com.mygdx.game;

public class Player {
    private Color color;

    public Player() {
    }
}
```

```java
package com.mygdx.game;

public class King extends Piece {

    private Location location;
    private Type type = Type.KING;
    private Player player;

    public King(Player player, Location location) {
        super(player, location);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void move() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void capture() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

```java
package com.mygdx.game;

public class Location {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Location(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;

public abstract class Piece extends Actor {
    private Location location;
    private Type type;
    private Player player;

    public Piece(Player player, Location location) {
        this.player = player;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public abstract void draw();

    public abstract void move();

    public abstract void capture();

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return this.location;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return this.player;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Touchable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.MoveByAction;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;

public class Soldier extends Actor {
    private Location location;
    private Type type = Type.SOLDIER;
    private Player player;
    Sprite sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("black_solider.png")));

    public Soldier(Player player, Location location) {
        //super(player, location);
        setBounds(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight());
        setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

        addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean keyDown(InputEvent event, int keycode) {
                if (keycode == Input.Keys.RIGHT) {
                    MoveByAction mba = new MoveByAction();
                    mba.setAmount(100f, 0f);
                    mba.setDuration(5f);

                    Soldier.this.addAction(mba);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        sprite.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
    }

    //@Override
    public void move() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    //@Override
    public void capture() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return this.location;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return this.player;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    Stage stage;
    private GUI gui;
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    float r_brown = (float) 163 / 255;
    float g_brown = (float) 102 / 255;
    float b_brown = (float) 46 / 255;

    float r_cream = (float) 240 / 255;
    float g_cream = (float) 187 / 255;
    float b_cream = (float) 108 / 255;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        ScreenViewport viewport = new ScreenViewport();
        stage = new Stage(viewport);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        gui = new GUI(shapeRenderer, camera);

        Soldier piece1 = new Soldier(new Player(), new Location(400, 400));
        stage.addActor(piece1);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                    if ((j % 2) == 0) {
                        shapeRenderer.setColor(r_brown, g_brown, b_brown, 1);
                        shapeRenderer.rect(100 * i, 100 * j, 100, 100);
                    } else {
                        shapeRenderer.setColor(r_cream, g_cream, b_cream, 1);
                        shapeRenderer.rect(100 * i, 100 * j, 100, 100);
                    }
                } else {
                    if ((j % 2) == 0) {

                        shapeRenderer.setColor(r_cream, g_cream, b_cream, 1);
                        shapeRenderer.rect(100 * i, 100 * j, 100, 100);
                    } else {
                        shapeRenderer.setColor(r_brown, g_brown, b_brown, 1);
                        shapeRenderer.rect(100 * i, 100 * j, 100, 100);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        shapeRenderer.end();
        camera.update();

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();

        /*
        Piece[][] pieces = new Piece[8][8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                Piece currentPiece = pieces[i][j];
                currentPiece.draw();
            }
        }
        */
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        shapeRenderer.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also get the most basic tutorial up and running, and make it draw something on screen. And then do tiny changes to that, and if something goes wrong, you can always revert back. You may also find it helpful to learn and use 'git' - If you learn and use git, you can more easily revert back to previous versions of your code that work, especially if you only commit while the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few quick and superficial pointers:

You seem to have multiple challenges and problems. Focus on them one at a time if you can, dividing and conquering them one by one.

If you are doing this for the sake of learning and you are very new to programming, be very careful about not having a large scope for the project. Set a very modest goal for what you want to be able to do with the project, and once you have accomplished that, you can add an additional goal. Iteratively continuing. This is very risk-resilient, because you start from a relatively easy point and go from there. The drawback with this is that you may have to do a fair amount of work, because one design early one that was suitable then may not be suitable for later work, and this may require a rewrite and redesign to a smaller or larger degree. Once you get more experienced, planning and seeking to design early on can be very, very helpful, especially if you know that some important aspects are going to be important later and the design you choose early on will impact these - but again, this is once you are more experienced.

Consider what things you would like the game to be able to have, like AI (state-space-search), graphics, saving/loading, the player using a GUI to move around, etc. And then pick the few things that you consider both easy and most nice to have. If you are new, don't require it to be a cohesive whole, you can always take that on later as a more ambitious goal once you have more experience, have learned more, thought more about things, etc. Again, be very, very modest with your goals and scope, and get some experience and just learn.